How to integrate omnidirectional base and redundant manipulator
I have been working on integrating a panda (from Franka Emika) and a summit-xl-steel in ROS noetic. I am not an expert on ROS, but I have integrated the two xacro files, and now I get an error saying the following:
[ WARN] [1712256167.592355858, 0.001000000]: Joint 'robot__joint1' contains a 'transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission' transmission, but it's not part of the Franka robot. Ignoring this joint in FrankaHWSim

From what I can understand this seems to be due to the fact that the franka is using a custom hardware interface, and the summit-xl-steel is not. Apparently different hardware interfaces are not supported. Does this mean that I am supposed to integrate the two or am I misunderstanding something?

Do you have a link to where you got the info about "the franka is using a custom hardware interface, and the summit-xl-steel is not. Apparently different hardware interfaces are not supported". Please [edit] your question and add the link, if possible. Thanks.

It depends on whether the issue lies with panda or summit-xl-steel - if the former then it might be worth raising a Github issue on the franka_ros repository.
There are (at least) a couple of similar sounding issues already:

this post on Panda with mobile robot gazebo crash #313
gazebo doesnt find joints when uploading two panda robots #372

